# Зачем нужен JNDI, если есть Spring IoC container (dependency lookup)?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

Пишут, что JNDI нужен для того, чтобы мы могли из Java-кода получить Java-объект из некоторой "Регистратуры" объектов по имени объекта, привязанного к этому объекту. В Спринге есть подобный механизм (Dependency lookup) где мы можем аналогично получать объект по его имени. Зачем тогда нужен JNDI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNDI это API из стандартной библиотеки. Этот API был [создан](https://web.archive.org/web/20040908114732/http://www.sun.com/smi/Press/sunflash/1997-03/sunflash.970310.10204.html) еще в 1997 году за 5 лет до того, как появилась первая версия spring в 2002. Далеко не все проекты используют spring, и нужен стандартный способ регистрации и поиска ресурсов. JNDI как раз и предоставляет такую возможность.